# What is a Hilbert space filter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, research-level, quantum-information, quantum-teleportation

In a recent paper,

> *Side-Channel-Free Quantum Key Distribution,* by Samuel L. Braunstein and Stefano Pirandola. *Phys. Rev. Lett.* **108**, 130502 (2012). [doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.130502](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.130502), [arXiv:1109.2330](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2330),

the authors repeatedly claim that

> *the dual teleportation channel act(s) as an ideal Hilbert space filter[...]*

What do they mean by a Hilbert space filter?

How does teleportation act as a Hilbert space filter?

Comment: It's described in the 1999 Lo-Chau article in science, reference 17 here. You may also try to look at http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/schmuel/papers/bp12.pdf It's a filter against any side channel.

Comment: @LubošMotl: Why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

*(I'm copy-pasting from @Luboš Motl's [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26932/what-is-a-hilbert-space-filter#comment59821_26932) into this community wiki.)*

> It's described in the 1999 Lo-Chau article in science, reference 17
>   here. You may also try to look at
>   [www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/schmuel/papers/bp12.pdf](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/schmuel/papers/bp12.pdf) It's a filter against
>   any side channel.